# 'Dot Product' on a Vectors Space over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, boolean-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $\mathbb{F}_2$ be the field with 2 elements, and consider $\mathbb{F}_2^n$, the space of all $n$-tuples over $\mathbb{F}_2$. This is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$, and we may introduce the following 'dot product' for every pair of vectors $x,y$ in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ ; if $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$, we define

$$\langle x,y\rangle:=x_1y_1+\cdots+x_ny_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i$$

Clearly this is a symmetric bilinear form, and my question is : when does this form become non-degenerate? More precisely,

> For which subspaces $V$ (of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$) does the induced bilinear form $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_2$ become non-degenerate?

I've been struggling with this problem for quite a while, but still don't see how to approach in the right way. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: It might help to note that given two vectors, what matters here is the number of places in which they both have a $1$. If this number is even, then they are orthogonal, and otherwise they are not. For the form to be non-degenerate on a subspace, for each vector in that subspace, it needs to contain another vector not orthogonal to it, i.e. which has an odd number of places in which they both have $1$s. In particular, this means that the focus needs to be on vectors with an even number of $1$s.

Comment: I doubt there are characterizations significantly different from the definition. It suffices to check a basis. One way of phrasing it is $V\subseteq V^\perp.$

Comment: The restriction to $V$ is non-degenerate if and only if $V$ and $V^\perp$ intersect trivially if and only if $V+V^\perp=\Bbb{F}_2^n$. It is a bit unclear what more you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be easier to talk about subspaces on which it becomes degenerate. This means subspaces $V$ containing a nonzero vector $v$ such that $\langle v, w \rangle = 0$ for all $w \in V$. In particular, $v$ must satisfy $\langle v, v \rangle = 0$; such vectors are called null vectors or isotropic vectors, and for this particular bilinear form they are precisely the vectors $v \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$ with an even number of nonzero entries.

Given a nonzero vector $v$, the orthogonal complement

$$v^{\perp} = \{ w \in \mathbb{F}_2^n : \langle v, w \rangle = 0 \}$$

can be explicitly described as follows. If $v$ has nonzero entries in the indices $i_1, \dots i_k$, then $\langle v, w \rangle = 0$ iff among the $i_1, \dots i_k$th entries of $w$ an even number of them are nonzero.

Every degenerate subspace $V$ can be constructed by taking an isotropic vector $v$ and then letting $V$ be any subspace of $v^{\perp}$ containing $v$. This isn't quite as good as a classification, though. It would be nice to be able to count the degenerate subspaces, since there are finitely many of them. One relevant keyword here should be "isotropic Grassmannian."